# writing tables from r to latex without changing decimal format

Tags: pdftex, r

I have ran a set regression in r and collected some of the statistics in a data frame format: variable|coefficient|s.e.|p-val|control|....| I am now writing that table using a template on my desktop saved as template.txt. When I write it in the following format it distorts the display so that values which should be displayed as [0.000] are displayed as [0]. Not a very critical problem but it messes up the aesthetic. Any way I can solve this?:

writetab(filename ="/Users/xx/Dropbox/project/tabfig/tables/overall_regs.tex", values = overall_regs, template="/Users/xx/Dropbox/project/templates/overall_regs.txt")

Comment: Without a minimal working example is hard to guess what are you doing exactly, and moreover we cannot reproduce the problem. Said, that, for instance, with `digits` in `xtable` you can control the decimals of each column in a table. There are many examples [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469083/11604),    [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393876/11604) and [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129680/11604).

Comment: More specific example with regression table: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549338/11604

Comment: thanks that really helps